# How to block user of using program interface while waiting for a thread?

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, delphi, vcl, delphi-10-seattle

I have software that today opens up a Modal Dialog and fires a thread to execute a long calculation process.

The Modal Dialog is a way to block the user of executing anything else in the program, except the Cancel button on the dialog, that will force the thread to finish.

However, it is not quite nice this approach in my interface. I wanted that the ProgressBar and the Cancel button to be part of my MainForm and while executing the background thread everything else is disabled except this specific Cancel Button.

How can it be done?

Comment: I guess by setting all components Enabled property to false except the cancel button ? You could do this in a loop

Comment: if you're going to block the user, why execute a background thread in the first place?  Seems easier to execute in the main thread and not have to deal with this issue ...

Comment: @JohnEasley the problem is keep responsiveness of the MainForm so that I can use the Cancel Button and it responds quickly

Comment: @EduardoE I'd be tempted to use a modal form with a progress bar or spinning activity indicator and a cancel button.  No need to meddle with the other controls and it gives the user some indication of what's occurring.  In fact I have done this in the past. Regards,

Comment: @MichaelVincent's approach means that the user doesn't get frustrated with your program not responding to input.

Comment: @MichaelVincent This is what I am doing right now.... But I wanted to get rid of the modal dialog, and integrate the ProgressBar to my MainForm, it would looks better for my interface and eventually I can give more information. However I loose the Modal Dialog benefit of blocking the user from other unwanted actions

Comment: @EduardoE sorry, I should've read your question properly and again before posting my comment.  My apologies.  How about a frameless transparent modal dialog the same size as the main form?

Comment: Stick with what you're doing. Just put the progress bar on your dialog. There's no point in going to the **trouble** (_handling user closing app, disabling all controls/actions/shortcuts_) of giving your user non-modal access if they can't do anything other than cancel in any case. Now of course, if you want to allow your user to do other things such as view old calculations (but not start a new one until the current is cancelled or finished) - then that's another story...

Comment: It's just going to upset your users to let them click on your UI and have it ignore them.

Comment: Any operation that the user tries to start that should not be started while the thread is running can simply be ignored and you should display a message box to tell the user to wait until the current operation is finished first. Leave the rest of the UI to perform its normal functions. No need to actually block anything that does not need to be blocked.

Comment: @Remy The question indicates that everything should be blocked

Comment: I also think Remy suggestion would be best because it will not annoy your users as much. I personally hate when application simply blocks all of its operation while performing some task. Sure I understand that the application needs to block some parts because using them might corrupt the data that is being used by that long operation. But is should not be blocking parts that won't interfere with that long operation. Because if it does then it is only killing the end use productivity as he/she hast to wait for that operation to be finished. And nowadays productivity is the most important factor

Comment: If you must run a thread and disable everything else I'd create a boolean, for example "CalculationRunning". In other functions / procedures check if true or false. If CaclulationRunning then Exit else DoStuff.

Comment: @Silver the question is clear that all operations need to be blocked. Do you have extra information on why you feel that is not so. What do you know about the program that we don't.

Comment: Why not place a transparent control over the form with the progressbar & cancel button on it? This will keep controls visible but not clickable and by "greying" the controls below it, it's clear for the user you cannot click it. But it's not modal so there's no interference with your app being in front of other apps the user might want to work with while waiting

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No I don't have any additional information. But I'm stating my opinion that OP might not be using the best approach with a comment. If I can't do this on SO any more then I guess I'll go trying to help people somewhere else. You see that is why I'm here. I'm trying to help other developers as best as I can whether this is by providing a direct solution to question or trying to point asker to possible alternate approach of solving the problem. ...

Comment: ... Now I understand that you try to keep SO clean with useful content. And I would also understand if you would react this way if I would wrote that as an answer. But as a comment? I think you are overreacting a bit.

Comment: It's just that you don't have enough information to state the recommendations that you do